# Why does R turns NAs in one cell to a row of NAs?

Tags: r, excel, csv

I run in to problems when I import csv files created in excel into R. Rows containing missing data but with time stamps are expressed in as a row of NAs.

I'm using R to work with the large datasets containing stream temperature and depth measurements collected by sensors. We have about three years of this data collected at 15 minute intervals. There are some small holes in the dataset which for other reasons I need expressed as a time stamp and NAs for the missing data. These holes are giving me problems in R.

I've collated all of the data in excel in a large file with 4 columns: date, time, depth, and temp. Then, I created a time stamp for all of the missing sampling periods and placed NA's:

```
date, time, temp, depth
10/10/10, 0:00:00, 20, 3
10/10/10, 0:15:00, 20, 3
10/10/10, 0:30:00, NA, NA
```

I saved the file in excel as a csv. Then, I import the file into R using read.csv(). Everything looks fine in str and when I print the data frame; however, in some instances R returns an entire row of NA's for rows missing the temp or depth data:

```
> str(blah)
'data.frame':   384 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ date  : Factor w/ 4 levels "10/10/10","10/11/10",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ time  : Factor w/ 96 levels "0:00:00","0:15:00",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 49 50 ...
 $ tempC : int  15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 ...
 $ depthm: int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...

> blah[blah$tempC == "NA",]
       date time tempC depthm
NA     <NA> <NA>    NA     NA
NA.1   <NA> <NA>    NA     NA
```

This can easily be recreated by making a test file in excel containing generated time & date series, some with fabricated temp and depth data and some rows with NAs. Does anyone know what is happening here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing "=="'s NA. Use `is.na()` instead:

```
blah[is.na( blah$tempC ), ]
```

The reason you got all NA's is what seems like a strange design decision but I've complained about it and been told that it's cast in stone. The "[" function returns a row of NA for any row that has an NA index. When using large dataframes it's a real pain to have a small fraction of your rows that generate an NA index show up in your output (.... .1% NA's out of 4 million will fill up your console with pages of junk). You either need to use `which` or use `...&!is.na(.)` in your "["-indexing, or use `subset` in interactive sessions.